# how to save user preferences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I have an app, and now, I need to save user's preferences.
I've done the following:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :setting
end
```

and

```
class Setting
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :user

  field :notify, type: Boolean
end
```

the question is: how can I make a form to save user's preferences? I have no idea at all...
anything is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
form_for current_user.settings || current_user.build_settings
```

Create also the controller

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    settings = Settings.new params[:settings]
    if settings.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Settings saved'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Settings could not be saved'
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def update
    settings = Settings.find params[:id]
    if settings.update_attributes params[:settings]
      flash[:notice] = 'Settings saved'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Settings could not be saved'
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Comment: I've made a form like this: https://gist.github.com/3029121 and I'm seeing `undefined method 'settings_path' for #<#<Class:0x95b5cd0>:0xa213234>`

Comment: Now it says I need the `create` method...how do I save this?

Comment: because you need to define that action in the controller.

Comment: I made something like this: https://gist.github.com/3029468 what is wrong? Why my redirect doesn't work? why, after save or update, the url goes to something like http://url/settings/4ff0b0bf4ccc4fa767000003

Comment: done with ` respond_to do |format|
      if current_user.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/dashboard', notice: 'Alteracoes salvas.' }
      end` thank you :D